# Signal R - Large Messages are not being passed from the client to server

Tags: .net, signalr

We get the "The Uri string is too long." error when passing a large message from a SignalR .NET client back to the SignalR server. Smaller messages work fine.

> APP Error sending data to SignalR Server: Invalid URI: The Uri string is too long.

The VB.NET Code for sending data back to the server:

```
Private Async Function SendData(ByVal sToUser As String, ByVal sToDevice As String, ByVal sDataType As String, ByVal sData As String) As Task
    Try
        myEvent = New CEvent(Now, sCompanyName, "INFO", "APP", "Sending data...", 100, 100)
        myEventLog.WriteCEvent(myEvent)

        Await trans.Invoke("sendData", _
                           New String() {msSiteCode, _
                                         sCompanyName, _
                                         sToUser & sToDevice, _
                                         sDataType, _
                                         sData}).ContinueWith(Function(task)
                                                                  If task.IsFaulted Then
                                                                      myEvent = New CEvent(Now, sCompanyName, "ERROR", "CCMDAPP", _
                                                                                              "APP Error sending data to SignalR Server: " & task.Exception.Message, 100, 100)
                                                                      myEventLog.WriteCEvent(myEvent)
                                                                  Else
                                                                      myEvent = New CEvent(Now, sCompanyName, "INFO", "CCMDAPP", _
                                                                                              "CCMDAPP Data sent to the SignalR Server with arguments: " & msSiteCode & " " & sCompanyName & " " & sToUser & sToDevice & " " & sData, 100, 100)
                                                                      myEventLog.WriteCEvent(myEvent)
                                                                  End If
                                                              End Function)
    Catch ex As Exception
        myEvent = New CEvent(Now, sCompanyName, "ERROR", "APP", "APP Error sending data to SignalR Server: " & ex.Message, 100, 100)
        myEventLog.WriteCEvent(myEvent)
    End Try
End Function
```

The Stack trace, enabled on the .NET SignalR Client for ALL. Please note that the message IDs 3 and 4 requested the large amount of data which was not sent back to the server.

> 06:09:38.5417500 - null - ChangeState(Disconnected, Connecting)
>
> 06:09:42.3567500 - f933feff-b1ae-41d8-b417-1fc114fdffdb - WS Connecting to: wss://www.example.com/SignalRServer/signalr/connect?transport=webSockets&connectionToken=wbsXZGWLigLa%2B7btvrZ7SZWcG%2FYOjtwE8ah8yqlhZdBVP%2FoM4COAkvwqihzLOIS%2FCHT5DbdQZzmgjVVEiNs33TAAIgfahlv3rQuE%2B%2FpLeszoGPr9REr%2FmUUpZPGWj3Gj&connectionData=[{"Name":"Transmitter"}]
>
> 06:09:42.3630000 - f933feff-b1ae-41d8-b417-1fc114fdffdb - Auto: Failed to connect to using transport webSockets. System.PlatformNotSupportedException: The WebSocket protocol is not supported on this platform.
>      at System.Net.WebSockets.ClientWebSocket..ctor()
>      at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Transports.WebSocketTransport.d__2.MoveNext()
>
> 06:09:42.3692500 - f933feff-b1ae-41d8-b417-1fc114fdffdb - SSE: GET https://www.example.com/SignalRServer/signalr/connect?transport=serverSentEvents&connectionToken=wbsXZGWLigLa%2B7btvrZ7SZWcG%2FYOjtwE8ah8yqlhZdBVP%2FoM4COAkvwqihzLOIS%2FCHT5DbdQZzmgjVVEiNs33TAAIgfahlv3rQuE%2B%2FpLeszoGPr9REr%2FmUUpZPGWj3Gj&connectionData=[{"Name":"Transmitter"}]
>
> 06:09:43.1605000 - f933feff-b1ae-41d8-b417-1fc114fdffdb - SSE: OnMessage(Data: initialized)
>
> 06:09:43.1630000 - f933feff-b1ae-41d8-b417-1fc114fdffdb - SSE: OnMessage(Data: {"C":"d-AA7FBA87-B,F0|GF,0|GG,1|GH,0","S":1,"M":[{"H":"Transmitter","M":"joined","A":["f933feff-b1ae-41d8-b417-1fc114fdffdb","19/12/2013 4:13:37 PM"]}]})
>
> 06:09:43.1817500 - f933feff-b1ae-41d8-b417-1fc114fdffdb - ChangeState(Connecting, Connected)
>
> 06:09:44.5080000 - f933feff-b1ae-41d8-b417-1fc114fdffdb - SSE: OnMessage(Data: {"C":"d-AA7FBA87-B,F0|GF,1|GG,1|GH,0","M":[{"H":"Transmitter","M":"isLoggedIn","A":[true,"","",""]}]})
>
> 06:09:44.5080000 - f933feff-b1ae-41d8-b417-1fc114fdffdb - OnMessage({"I":"0"})
>
> 06:09:45.4905000 - f933feff-b1ae-41d8-b417-1fc114fdffdb - SSE: OnMessage(Data: {"C":"d-AA7FBA87-B,F0|GF,2|GG,1|GH,0","M":[{"H":"Transmitter","M":"commandSent","A":["{\"MsgID\":\"0\",\"CompanyCode\":\"ACCOUNTS: xyz SOFTWARE P/L V90\",\"FromUser\":\"username@example.com\",\"FromDevice\":\"16\",\"Action\":3,\"ObjectType\":16,\"Params\":[\"A1\"]}"]}]})
>
> 06:09:45.5242500 - f933feff-b1ae-41d8-b417-1fc114fdffdb - SSE: OnMessage(Data: {"C":"d-AA7FBA87-B,F0|GF,5|GG,1|GH,0","M":[{"H":"Transmitter","M":"commandSent","A":["{\"MsgID\":\"1\",\"CompanyCode\":\"ACCOUNTS: xyz SOFTWARE P/L V90\",\"FromUser\":\"username@example.com\",\"FromDevice\":\"16\",\"Action\":3,\"ObjectType\":36,\"Params\":[\"Job Maintenance\"]}"]},{"H":"Transmitter","M":"commandSent","A":["{\"MsgID\":\"2\",\"CompanyCode\":\"ACCOUNTS: xyz SOFTWARE P/L V90\",\"FromUser\":\"username@example.com\",\"FromDevice\":\"16\",\"Action\":3,\"ObjectType\":23,\"Params\":[\"username@example.com\",\"username@example.com\",\"0\"]}"]},{"H":"Transmitter","M":"commandSent","A":["{\"MsgID\":\"3\",\"CompanyCode\":\"ACCOUNTS: xyz SOFTWARE P/L V90\",\"FromUser\":\"username@example.com\",\"FromDevice\":\"16\",\"Action\":3,\"ObjectType\":5,\"Params\":[\"\",\"ACTIVE\",\"50\"]}"]}]})
>
> 06:09:46.0342500 - f933feff-b1ae-41d8-b417-1fc114fdffdb - OnMessage({"I":"1"})
>
> 06:09:46.5655000 - f933feff-b1ae-41d8-b417-1fc114fdffdb - OnMessage({"I":"2"})
>
> 06:09:46.5680000 - f933feff-b1ae-41d8-b417-1fc114fdffdb - OnMessage({"I":"4"})
>
> 06:09:46.6005000 - f933feff-b1ae-41d8-b417-1fc114fdffdb - OnMessage({"I":"3"})
>
> 06:09:46.7567500 - f933feff-b1ae-41d8-b417-1fc114fdffdb - OnMessage({"I":"5"})
>
> 06:09:47.2567500 - f933feff-b1ae-41d8-b417-1fc114fdffdb - OnMessage({"I":"7"})
>
> 06:09:47.4930000 - f933feff-b1ae-41d8-b417-1fc114fdffdb - OnMessage({"I":"6"})
>
> 06:10:20.4480000 - f933feff-b1ae-41d8-b417-1fc114fdffdb - SSE: OnMessage(Data: {})
>
> 06:11:20.4792500 - f933feff-b1ae-41d8-b417-1fc114fdffdb - SSE: OnMessage(Data: {})
>
> 06:12:20.5005000 - f933feff-b1ae-41d8-b417-1fc114fdffdb - SSE: OnMessage(Data: {})
>
> 06:12:50.5242500 - f933feff-b1ae-41d8-b417-1fc114fdffdb - SSE: OnMessage(Data: {"C":"d-AA7FBA87-B,F1|GF,5|GG,1|GH,0","M":[{"H":"Transmitter","M":"leave","A":["45fccfd7-5928-430f-867d-b5c7682812fc","19/12/2013 4:16:45 PM"]}]})
>
> 06:13:20.5280000 - f933feff-b1ae-41d8-b417-1fc114fdffdb - SSE: OnMessage(Data: {})
>
> 06:14:20.5555000 - f933feff-b1ae-41d8-b417-1fc114fdffdb - SSE: OnMessage(Data: {})
>
> 06:15:05.5292500 - f933feff-b1ae-41d8-b417-1fc114fdffdb - SSE: OnMessage(Data: {"C":"d-AA7FBA87-B,F1|GF,6|GG,1|GH,0","M":[{"H":"Transmitter","M":"commandSent","A":["{\"MsgID\":\"4\",\"CompanyCode\":\"ACCOUNTS: xyz SOFTWARE P/L V90\",\"FromUser\":\"username@example.com\",\"FromDevice\":\"16\",\"Action\":3,\"ObjectType\":5,\"Params\":[\"\",\"ACTIVE\",\"50\"]}"]}]})
>
> 06:15:06.5392500 - f933feff-b1ae-41d8-b417-1fc114fdffdb - OnMessage({"I":"9"})

**ENVIRONMENT:**

- Signal R Server on Windows 2012 server/Windows 7.
- Signal R .NET Client on Windows 7 machines.

We use async calls, but as far as we understand it, we need async calls for compatibility with windows 8 and windows server 2012 machines.

Also, the issue appeared as a result of upgrading from signal R release 1.1.0 to 2.0.1 and no other changes were made. Async calls were added much before this upgrade.

---

Is there some setting we can set to prevent this? Or this is indeed a limitation of SignalR 2.0.1 and we need to devise a way to chunkify larger messages?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace please?

Comment: Done. Have added the Stack trace as requested.